# How can I get style code to make this button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the button for adding event  but they have not displayed there style code. How can i get there full cascading style sheet.

( https://www.addevent.com/documentation/add-to-calendar-button )

Comment: Have you looked in your browser dev tools (F12)? They have very good CSS information.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the styles of an element by inspecting it from your browser's developer tools.
*e.g.* in Google Chrome's Developer Tools: *Elements* → *Styles*.

```css
.addeventatc {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99998;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Optima, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Candara, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #000!important;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 13px 12px 12px 43px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased!important;
  outline-color: rgba(0, 78, 255, 0.5);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 0%);
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.5px rgba(50, 50, 93, .17), 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(50, 50, 93, .1), 0 1px 1.5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .07), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .08), 0 0 0 0 transparent!important;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.addevent.com/libs/imgs/icon-calendar-t5.png), url(https://cdn.addevent.com/libs/imgs/icon-calendar-t1.svg), url(https://cdn.addevent.com/libs/imgs/icon-apple-t5.svg), url(https://cdn.addevent.com/libs/imgs/icon-facebook-t5.svg), url(https://cdn.addevent.com/libs/imgs/icon-google-t5.svg), url(https://cdn.addevent.com/libs/imgs/icon-office365-t5.svg), url(https://cdn.addevent.com/libs/imgs/icon-outlook-t5.svg), url(https://cdn.addevent.com/libs/imgs/icon-outlookcom-t5.svg), url(https://cdn.addevent.com/libs/imgs/icon-yahoo-t5.svg);
  background-position: -9999px -9999px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.addeventatc .start,
.addeventatc .end,
.addeventatc .timezone,
.addeventatc .title,
.addeventatc .description,
.addeventatc .location,
.addeventatc .organizer,
.addeventatc .organizer_email,
.addeventatc .facebook_event,
.addeventatc .all_day_event,
.addeventatc .date_format,
.addeventatc .alarm_reminder,
.addeventatc .recurring,
.addeventatc .attendees,
.addeventatc .calname,
.addeventatc .uid,
.addeventatc .sequence,
.addeventatc .status,
.addeventatc .method,
.addeventatc .client,
.addeventatc .transp {
  display: none!important;
}

.addeventatc .addeventatc_icon {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 12px;
  top: 10px;
  background: url(https://cdn.addevent.com/libs/imgs/icon-calendar-t1.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 18px 18px;
}
```

```html
<div title="" class="addeventatc" id="addeventatc1" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" translate="no" data-loaded="true" style="visibility: visible;">
  Add to Calendar
  <span class="start atc_node notranslate">03/31/2022 08:00 AM</span>
  <span class="end atc_node notranslate">03/31/2022 10:00 AM</span>
  <span class="timezone atc_node notranslate">America/Los_Angeles</span>
  <span class="title atc_node notranslate">Summary of the event</span>
  <span class="description atc_node notranslate">Description of the event</span>
  <span class="location atc_node notranslate">Location of the event</span>
  <span class="addeventatc_icon atc_node notranslate"></span>
</div>
```